# RegEx: find and replace EOL between quotes

Tags: regex, autohotkey

In a multi-line string like this:

```
She Loves You [Mono],"Past Masters, Vol. 1",4,"She loves you, yeah, yeah, yeah
She loves you, yeah, yeah, yeah
She loves you, yeah, yeah, yeah, yeah"
Eight Days A Week,Beatles For Sale,8,"Eight days a week
I love you.
Eight days a week
Is not enough to show I care."
```

I want to replace EOL (\r\n) **between the quotes** with a replacement character like "¶" (ASCII code 182) to make this string single-line.

The result would be:

```
She Loves You [Mono],"Past Masters, Vol. 1",4,"She loves you, yeah, yeah, yeah¶She loves you, yeah, yeah, yeah¶She loves you, yeah, yeah, yeah, yeah"
Eight Days A Week,Beatles For Sale,8,"Eight days a week¶I love you.¶Eight days a week¶Is not enough to show I care."
```

I tried various RegEx related solutions found on StackOverflow but I was not able to adapt them to what I want.

I will use this RegEx expression in the AHK function:

```
RegExReplace(Haystack, NeedleRegEx [, Replacement = "", OutputVarCount = "", Limit = -1, StartingPosition = 1])

RegExReplace(MyText, NeedleRegEx???, "¶")
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: No, it wont fix it. The challenge is to do the replacement only between the quotes.

Comment: I'll make my question more clear about it.

Comment: My question was not clear enough. I mentioned the "between quotes" requirement only in the title and did not state it again the the question itself. Sorry about that. Please see the edited question.

Comment: Knowing whether you're between quotes or not is being context-aware, something regex is terrible at and which is better left to smarter parsers or dumb but custom-made parsers. I don't know AHK well at all, but I think you should aim at extracting the quoted parts, making the search/replace in these parts then updating them back (or reconstructing the whole string). That or the custom-made parser (read char, negate "inside-quotes" bool if quote encountered, change linefeed to ¶ or not depending on bool, output char)

Comment: Yes. This is what I'm doing in my current script, parsing the whole file and replacing taking care of the quotes context. But I was wondering if a RegEx expression could do it in a more efficient way. Thanks for the input Aaron.

Comment: A regex solution would need a variable-width lookbehind to check whether there is an odd number of quotes between the start of the string and the currently tested token. This feature is implemented in very few regex engines, and it would be terribly inefficient (having to match back the whole string for each new token encountered). I cringe at the idea of this kind of code in production having to be maintained by someone else because they discover that some quotes can be escaped and shouldn't be considered as an enclosing quote. It would also fail to raise an error with unbalanced quotes.

Comment: This is not a solution. But this is a good answer. I would mark it if I could :-)

Comment: Well I could rewrite it properly as an answer... I don't have the time right now but I may do so later :)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string and operate on it that way maybe?

```
str = 
(
She Loves You [Mono],"Past Masters, Vol. 1",4,"She loves you, yeah, yeah, yeah
She loves you, yeah, yeah, yeah
She loves you, yeah, yeah, yeah, yeah"
Eight Days A Week,Beatles For Sale,8,"Eight days a week
I love you.
Eight days a week
Is not enough to show I care."
)
outStr := ""
Loop, Parse, str, `"
{
    field := A_LoopField
    StringReplace, field, field, `r,, All
    StringReplace, field, field, `n, ¶, All
    outStr .= field
}
MsgBox % outStr
ExitApp
```

Comment: I'm not looking for a "simple replacement". The challenge is to do the replacement only between the quotes, not all of them as your simple solution would do.

Comment: You'll have to parse the string. I modified my answer.

Comment: Thank you fischgeek. This is close to what is needed (if no RegEx can do it faster on very large files. But there is an issue with this script: the quotes around values must not be removed. Example: "Past Masters, Vol. 1" and "She loves you, ... yeah" must keep their quotes encapsulators.

A friend from AHK forum sent me a variation of this. I'll post it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems that there is no solution using RegEx only, I post here a solution written by maestrith (on AHK Forum). It does replace the EOL inside quotes, keeping the quotes encapsulators. It reads and process the whole content using StrSplit to isolate quoted sections, processing them with a combination of RegExReplace and StringReplace. I still have to test it on a very large file to see how it performs compared to another script I wrote that process the content one char at a time.

```
#SingleInstance,Force
info=
(
She Loves You [Mono],"Past Masters, Vol. 1",4,"She loves you, yeah, yeah, yeah
She loves you, yeah, yeah, yeah
She loves you, yeah, yeah, yeah, yeah"
Eight Days A Week,Beatles For Sale,8,"Eight days a week
I love you.
Eight days a week
Is not enough to show I care."
)
for a,b in StrSplit(info,Chr(34)){
    if(!Mod(A_Index,2)){
        replace:=RegExReplace(b,"\R",chr(182))
        StringReplace,info,info,%b%,%Replace%
    }
}
Gui,Font,s10
Gui,Add,Edit,w1000 h200 -Wrap,%Info%
Gui,Show
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll add this as an answer even if it does not answer my original question. This does not use RegEx but, in the end, is faster than the tentative in the earlier answer (roughly 3x to 5x faster on a 3 megs csv file).

```
#SingleInstance,Force
info=
(
She Loves You [Mono],"Past Masters, Vol. 1",4,"She loves you, yeah, yeah, yeah
She loves you, yeah, yeah, yeah
She loves you, yeah, yeah, yeah, yeah"
Eight Days A Week,Beatles For Sale,8,"Eight days a week
I love you.
Eight days a week
Is not enough to show I care."
)
blnInsideEncapsulators := false
Loop, Parse, info
    ; parsing on a temporary copy of info -  so we can update the original info inside the loop
{
    if (A_Index = 1)
        info := ""
    if (blnInsideEncapsulators AND A_Loopfield = "`n")
        info := info . Chr(182)
    else
        info := info . A_Loopfield
    if (A_Loopfield = """")
        blnInsideEncapsulators := !blnInsideEncapsulators ; beginning or end of encapsulated text
}
Gui,Font,s10
Gui,Add,Edit,w1000 h200 -Wrap,%Info%
Gui,Show
```

I will leave this thread without accepted answer in case someone comes with a full RegEx solution. Never know...

Thanks all for your input.